# How do I save the hard drives from a broken Dell XPS 700 motherbord?

Tags: raid, dell-xps

I have an old XPS 700, and the motherboard just died (this is a common issue with this model, my 3rd MB). I'm not interested in reviving the computer itself, but would like to access the data on the disks. The drives were set up as a RAID0.

Are RAID controllers commonly interchangeable, are there a few different types?

What am I looking for (in the XPS 700 documentation) to be able to find similar raid controllers that are likely to work?

Does anyone have any success doing this, what equipment did you use?

Comment: Too bad you were using RAIDO (striping). You can't just put the drive into a cheap enclosure. If it was software RAID, like using `md` in Linux, you could just configure the same software to read your data. But if it was hardware RAID, you indeed have to be careful to get the same controller.

Answer (score 2):

They are interchangeable so long as the hardware is of the same type (SATA,PCI etc). There are some motherboards that support it though, so that is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware RAID controllers are not commonly interchangeable.

If you are lucky and you have a similar card from the same brand then you may be able to use the disks with a newer cards. But if you use a card from another manufacturer or of a different design then all bets are off.

> are there a few different types?

There are. Fibre interface. SAS (also works with SATA), SATA (only works with SATA), plain old paralel SCSI, ...